# Combine rows from different sheets that share two column values - Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The scenario is that within a workbook, I have one sheet with toy proposals for different animals. Another sheet collects form responses for evaluations to determine if the toys are safe. The proposals and forms collect different information that I would like to be combined into one row for a given toy/species.

Sample Google Sheet w/ edit access:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LHCsD2Mb4evqSDqhu6VyGFqcN2g-0WdKSYrfkl6rA1I/edit?usp=sharing

I am new to apps script, and am not finding a tutorial on how to achieve this. Any assistance or guidance in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could just set a new column in 'Toy Proposals' that puts in different columns of the same row the comments about that product
[image: ![enter image description here]

With this formula:

```
   =arrayformula(if(A2:A="","",split(byrow(A2:A,lambda(each,if(each="","",join("|",query({arrayformula('Form Responses'!B:B&"|"&'Form Responses'!C:C),'Form Responses'!D:D},"Select Col2 where Col1 = '"&arrayformula(each&"|"&offset(each,0,1))&"'"))))),"|")))
```

Comment: PS: added some extra rows to show the result

Comment: This is a very helpful suggestion, thank you. I am a novice and unable to make sense of this advanced formula to apply it to other sheets. Would you be able to offer a description of how the formula works, or point me towards resources that might help me to learn?

Comment: In order two compare both columns I joined them with "|" and made a query to find the matches and return the form responses in ColD. Byrow helps to do it row by row.. "each" is A2, A3, A4 respectively... And OFFSET let me take also the values of B2, B3, B4...

Comment: BYROW helps me repeat the process, but only returns one value per row that's why I had to join all the results of each row. And then finally splitted them. The first If checks if the value is empty then it returns empty, so you don't have tons of tried with error after your last product

Comment: Hope it starts to make sense at least, ask if you need anything!